# Using lerp in LWJGL3?

Tags: java, lwjgl

How can I utilize my `lerp` function inside the `vector3f` class? Currently the `lerp` function reads like so:

```
public Vector3f lerp(Vector3f other, float alpha) {
    return this.scale(1f - alpha).add(other.scale(alpha));
}
```

I have `position` and `velocity` vectors which use the `add` function as it updates. Now I want some smooth movement, but, I'm unsure how you would correctly use `lerp`. I've watched and read a few tutorials but none of them seem to address this kind of functionality. Any help would be much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

So I've been watching this video [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nq3yhwsrNNw) he has a series of videos on lerp with a very good diagram demonstration, which gave me a clue as to how linear interpolation works, so I decided to give it another shot. I wrote a new Vector2f method like so.

```
    public Vector2f lerpT(Vector2f currentPos, Vector2f newPos, float alpha)
{
    return currentPos.scale(1f - alpha).add(newPos.scale(alpha));
    //return Vector3f point1 + alpha * (point2 - point1);
}
```

And my main class is like so:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    init();
}

public static void init() {

    Vector2f currentPosition = new Vector2f(0.3f,0.7f);
    Vector2f newPosition = new Vector2f(1.3f,0.8f);

    Vector2f lerpPos = new Vector2f().lerpT(currentPosition, newPosition, 0f);

    System.out.println("Testing LERP: " + "5/01/2018" + "\n");
    System.out.println(lerpPos.x);
    System.out.println(lerpPos.y);

}
```

This is what gets printed out into the console.

X: 0.79999995
Y: 0.75

I found some graph paper and decided to map it which was useful. I calculated the formula with a calculator and I get the same values in the x and y's lerpPos vector that is calculated in the code. I also changed it to Vector2f to make it simpler. And instead of LWJGL I decided to make a simple console program in java. While I understand it a bit more, I'm unsure how I'm supposed to use a velocity vector with the lerp function so I can give something some acceleration(?). I see how the alpha in the formula is important, but I'm unsure how to utilize it. If anything, I'd like to tryout some easing in and easing out, but the witchcraft needed seems a little bit over my head just at this moment. Oh well, I'll keep trying.

I'm going to post my completed code to my github, I'll post a link here when I get it up and running .Again, any help would be much appreciated

UPDATE:

```
public class Player {

private TexturedModel model;
public Vector3f position;
public Vector3f velocity;
public Vector3f acceleration;
public static Vector3f direction;


public static float maxVelocity = 0.5f;
private float rotX, rotY, rotZ;
private float scaleX, scaleY, scaleZ;
private float maxHolder;
public Player(TexturedModel model, Vector3f position, float rotX, float rotY, float rotZ,
        float scaleX, float scaleY, float scaleZ) {
    this.model = model;
    this.rotX = rotX;
    this.rotY = rotY;
    this.rotZ = rotZ;
    this.scaleX = scaleX;
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
    this.scaleZ = scaleZ;
    this.position = position;

    Random random = new Random();

    position = new Vector3f();
    velocity = new Vector3f();
    acceleration = new Vector3f();
    direction = new Vector3f();
}

public void update() {
    velocity = velocity.add(acceleration);
    position = position.add(velocity);
    maxHolder = maxVelocity;
    //position.length()

    //Limit
    if (velocity.length() > maxVelocity) {
            velocity = velocity.normalize().scale(maxVelocity);
        }
        else if (velocity.dot(direction) < 0.0) {
            velocity = new Vector3f(0,0,0);
        }

}


public void movePlayer() {

    if (KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_D)) {
        this.acceleration.x = 0.001f;

    }

    if (KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)) {
        this.acceleration.x = -0.001f;

    }

    if (KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_W)) {
        this.acceleration.y = 0.001f;

    }

    if (KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_S)) {
        this.acceleration.y = -0.001f;

    }

    if (!KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_W) && !KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_S) && !KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_D) && !KeyboardInput.isKeyDown(GLFW_KEY_A)){ 
        this.velocity.x = 0;
        this.velocity.y = 0;
        this.velocity.z = 0;
        this.acceleration.x = 0f;
        this.acceleration.y = 0;
        this.acceleration.z = 0;
    }
}
public void applyForce(Vector3f force) {
    acceleration = force;
}

public void increasePosition(float dx, float dy, float dz) {
    this.velocity.x += dx;
    this.velocity.y += dy;
    this.velocity.z += dz;
}

public void increaseRotation(float dx, float dy, float dz) {
    this.rotX += dx;
    this.rotY += dy;
    this.rotZ += dz;
}

public TexturedModel getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(TexturedModel model) {
    this.model = model;
}

public void setVelocity(Vector3f velocity) {
    this.velocity = velocity;
}

public Vector3f getPosition() {
    return position;
}

public void setPosition(Vector3f position) {
    this.position = position;
}

public float getRotX() {
    return rotX;
}

public void setRotX(float rotX) {
    this.rotX = rotX;
}

public float getRotY() {
    return rotY;
}

public void setRotY(float rotY) {
    this.rotY = rotY;
}

public float getRotZ() {
    return rotZ;
}

public void setRotZ(float rotZ) {
    this.rotZ = rotZ;
}

public float getScaleX() {
    return scaleX;
}

public void setScaleX(float scaleX) {
    this.scaleX = scaleX;
}

public float getScaleY() {
    return scaleY;
}

public void setScaleY(float scaleY) {
    this.scaleY = scaleY;
}

public float getScaleZ() {
    return scaleZ;
}

public void setScaleZ(float scaleZ) {
    this.scaleZ = scaleZ;
}
```

}

Heres the current code: It accelerates but velocity snaps back to 0 as I let go of the key. I want it to decelerate. Conceptually it should be easy.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I watched this video which had the same concept that you're reffering to. https://youtu.be/qJq7I2DLGzI He has two vector3f, one called previousPosition. So could you calculate it as previousPosition.add(newPosition + velocity); ?? I'm still a little confused as to how this would work, especially where my velocity is already being used to change his position. I'm going to give it another go and see if I can get it working.

Comment: Sorry about the confusion, yes I'm trying to accelerate/decelerate the camera over time, as if the camera follows the player on the x axis. I feel like I'm not quite understanding the concept behind lerp and how its meant to be used. Currently I have a delta time setup, so at the moment, using that same code: I don't understand the definition I've read: Calculates a linear interpolation between this vector with another vector. param other The other vector. alpha The alpha value, must be between 0.0 and 1.0. return Linear interpolated vector.

Comment: I wrote camera.getPosition().lerp(???, 0.1f (delta time?); in the code and I don't quite understand what these particular variables do, even with the definition written from a silverTiger tutorial dealing with LWJGL3.

Comment: So I've been spending a few hours a day trying to understand this. I decided to get graph paper so I could understand it a better, and Jamie King and bunch of other guys have some hands on demonstration about how it works which was handy. I understand the formula to a larger degree but still don't know how to utilize it in orderto get the easing in and easing out movements, or even with a velocity vector or the time delta. Again, any suggestions would be much appreciated. I made an update in my main post. Thanks again.

Comment: So I've managed to get velocity and acceleration to work, the math made sense after a bit of study. My object will accelerate but because I have 0 velocity when not pushing a key, it will snap to 0. Not the effect i want. I want it to decelerate as I let go.